# MS Access SQL - Simple query that joins two other queries gives no results

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Can anyone tell me why this simple JOIN query gives me a table with no results?  When I run both the countINTmonth and countDEPTmonth queries separately, they give me the results I expect.  However, when I run the simple JOIN query, it gives me a table with the column names but no data--but also without any error message!

CountINTmonth query

```
SELECT Count(clients.ssn) AS CountofIntakes, month(clients.prog_start) AS Month2, year(clients.prog_start) AS Year2
FROM clients
WHERE clients.prog_start BETWEEN [Enter Start Date] AND [Enter End Date]
GROUP BY year(clients.prog_start), month(clients.prog_start)
ORDER BY year(clients.prog_start) DESC , month(clients.prog_start) DESC;
```

CountDEPTmonth query

```
SELECT Count(clients.ssn) AS CountOfDepartures, month(clients.[departure date]) AS Month1, year(clients.[departure date]) AS year1
FROM clients
WHERE clients.[departure date] BETWEEN [Enter Start Date] AND [Enter End Date]
GROUP BY year(clients.[departure date]), month(clients.[departure date])
ORDER BY year(clients.[departure date]) DESC , month(clients.[departure date]) DESC;
```

The query that joins the previous two

```
SELECT countdeptmonth.countofdepartures, countintmonth.countofintakes, countdeptmonth.month1, countdeptmonth.year1
FROM countdeptmonth
INNER JOIN
countintmonth
ON (countdeptmonth.year1=countintmonth.year2 AND countdeptmonth.month1=countintmonth.month2)
ORDER BY countdeptmonth.year1 DESC, countdeptmonth.month1 DESC
```

When I change the JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, the data appears except that the countofintakes column is empty.  When I change the JOIN to a RIGHT JOIN the only column that has data is the countofintakes.

NOTES ON THE TABLES
The CLIENTS table has a bunch of columns with different data points. The SSN is the primary key.  prog_start is a date field for when they started our treatment program. [departure date] is a date field for when they left our program. [Enter Start Date] and [Enter End Date] are supposed to be a date range that the user inputs when they run the query--the dates should be the same for both queries.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try joining on just the month without the year to see if you get matches.  Are you sure there are records that match both year and month?

Comment: I just tried joining on just the month, and still no data results.  Maybe I'm confused about the year/month records match.  When I run each separate query, for the same date range, they each have one row for every month of date range. So, in my mind, they should be able to join when the month and year both match.

Answer (score 1):

I may have solved my own problem.  I just added the MonthName function to the Month1 and Month2 columns.

```
MonthName(month(clients.prog_start)) AS Month2
```

And

```
MonthName(month(clients.[departure date])) AS Month1
```

Once I did that, the JOIN query showed the correct results.  I didn't even need to update the GROUP BY fields.

Anyone know why the query couldn't join on the just the number of the month and why it needed the name to join correctly?